# Making an element visible by hovering another element (without :hover-property)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, jquery-hover

Okay, here's the problem:

i have these three DIVs:

```
<div id="gestaltung_cd"></div>
<div id="gestaltung_illu"></div>
<div id="gestaltung_klassisch"></div>
```

…and these three DIVs – which are invisible (display:none;)– on a completely different position on the page:

```
<div id="mainhexa1"></div>
<div id="mainhexa2"></div>
<div id="mainhexa3"></div>
```

what i want to do is:
if i hover "gestaltung_cd" i want to make "mainhexa1" visible and if i hover "gestaltung_illu" i want to make "mainhexa2" visbile and so on…

as you can see, the three invisible DIVs are no child-elements of the first three ones... so ":hover" is not possible in this case. Is there an easy way to do this in JQuery?

thanks,
Jochen

Comment: Did you try to use jQuery's [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function ?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that i'm not very familiar with JQuery... do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the sibling selector. As long as div's share the same parent, you can still affect them with hover

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8LFWR/)

Vital Code:

```
#gestaltung_cd:hover ~ #mainhexa1,
#gestaltung_illu:hover ~ #mainhexa2,
#gestaltung_klassisch:hover ~ #mainhexa3 {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should precise the compatibility ?

Comment: Oh, I thought it came later to IE. My comment is thus irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

using jQuerys hover function, like this:

```
$('#gestaltung_cd').hover(function() {
    $('#mainhexa1').toggle();
});
```

(if you don't want to hide the div on blur, then change toggle() to show())

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery's [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function :

```
var divs = {
   cd:        'mainhexa1',
   illu:      'mainhexa2',
   klassisch: 'mainhexa3'
};
$('[id^=gestaltung]').hover(function(){ // selects all elements whose id starts with gestaltung
   $('#'+divs[this.id.slice('gestaltung_'.length)]).toggle();
});
```

Note that it might be easier to have some relation between the opener and opening elements, like a class or another attribute (as in nnnnnn's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do the first one and you'd just do the same for the other two with the relevant IDs.

```
$("#gestaltung_cd").hover(
function () {
    $("#mainhexa1").show();
},
function () {
    $("#mainhexa1").hide();
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#gestaltung_cd").hover(function({
    $("#mainhexa1").css({ "visibility": "visible" });
}, function() {
    //Your hover out function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you add an attribute to the first three divs that specifies which div to show on hover:

```
<div id="gestaltung_cd" data-maindiv="mainhexa1"></div>
<div id="gestaltung_illu" data-maindiv="mainhexa2"></div>
<div id="gestaltung_klassisch" data-maindiv="mainhexa3"></div>
```

That way you can handle the show/hide on hover with a single use of the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method:

```
$("div[data-maindiv]").hover(function() {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-maindiv") ).show();
},
function() {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-maindiv") ).hide();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GFMQR/

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap each block of divs in a container you can match them up by index, which will make the code work regardless of how many divs there are. Something like this:

```
<div class="gesaltung-container">
    <div id="gestaltung_cd">gestaltung_cd</div>
    <div id="gestaltung_illu">gestaltung_illu</div>
    <div id="gestaltung_klassisch">gestaltung_klassisch</div>
</div>
<div class="mainhexa-container">
    <div id="mainhexa1">mainhexa1</div>
    <div id="mainhexa2">mainhexa2</div>
    <div id="mainhexa3">mainhexa3</div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.gesaltung-container div').hover(
    function () {
        $('.mainhexa-container div').eq($(this).index()).show();
    },
    function () {
        $('.mainhexa-container div').eq($(this).index()).hide();
    }
);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4tAZS/)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record ...

You can do the effect you want only with CSS and HTML ( without javascript ), but you have to place your elements to follow each other and use `+` selector in CSS. Something like :

HTML

```
<div id="gestaltung_cd"></div>
<div id="mainhexa1"></div>
<div id="gestaltung_illu"></div>
<div id="mainhexa2"></div>
<div id="gestaltung_klassisch"></div>
<div id="mainhexa3"></div>
```

CSS

```
div#gestaltung_cd:hover + div#mainhexa1 {
   display:block;
}
div#gestaltung_illu:hover + div#mainhexa2 {
   display:block;
}
div#gestaltung_klassisch:hover + div#mainhexa3 {
   display:block;
}
```

you can check out the demo http://tinkerbin.com/KP17XUgq

Comment: You can do it without putting the elements following each other. Check my answer, it uses the `~` sibling selector

Comment: Yes ;) you are right too.. I saw your answer seconds after I posted mine. Although in production I use `+` since I don't specify div `ids`

Comment: It's useful to see how `+` works, but note that the OP explicitly stated that the hidden divs are "on a completely different position on the page".