# Why doesn't :hover affect another element in this example?

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover, nav

I'm trying to make a navbar with menu links on mobile that appears when you tap on the menu button. So, I decided to use `:hover` CSS events to make them appear.

[In this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14749475/3505377) ([or this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8LFWR/), `:hover` is used to make other elements visible, and it works fine.

Without all the other containers (`<nav>`, and other `<li>` elements outside of `#item` and `#menu`), the code works fine. However, when I implement it into my current structure, it stops working; `...:hover ~ ...` fails to work, while `...:hover` still works (being that `...` are the rule names).

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 196px;
  font-size: 64px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
}

nav ul {
  color: white;
  -webkit-padding-start: 32px;
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 18px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

nav ul li#title {
  min-width: 80%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li#menu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li#menu:hover {
  color: red !important;
}

nav ul li#menu:hover ~ nav ul li#item {
  color: red !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

nav ul li#item.first {
  margin-top: 32px;
}

nav ul li#item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  margin-left: -32px;
  height: 96px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

nav ul li#item:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}

a#menu {
  color: white !important;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a#menu:visited {
  color: white !important;
}

a:active {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="title">aytimothy's Website</li>
    <a href="javascript:;">
      <li id="menu"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true">=</i></li>
    </a>
    <a href="/blog">
      <li id="item" class="first item">Blog</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/forum">
      <li id="item" class="item">Forum</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/portfolio">
      <li id="item" class="item">Portfolio</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/support">
      <li id="item" class="item">Support</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

#### Intended Behaviour

Mousing over the equal sign (placeholder for the menu sign) will make itself and everything in the `li#item` elements red (for testing), and that the hidden elements (`li#item`) actually shows up (`nav ul li#menu:hover ~ nav ul li#item).

The background should turn transparent red when the user hovers over.

#### Unintended Behaviour

Hovering over the `=` sign only turns it red.

Comment: You have errors in your html: an <ul> cannot contain an <a> as a child. Fix that first. Also, `nav ul li#menu:hover ~ nav ul li#item` should be `nav ul li#menu:hover ~ li#item`, because the <li> is followed by the other <li>, not by a <nav>.

Comment: @MrLister Unfortunately, that (putting `<a>` in the `<li>`(s) and changing the CSS rule) did... Nothing (other than shrunk the CSS down a little).

Comment: Then something else must be going on. Can you update the question with the code you now have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors with your code:

1. Your html is incorrect - fix this by putting your anchors inside your lis
2. IDs must be unique - remove the multiple ids
3. Your css selector is completely wrong - you want to show any sibling li after the hovered one - you cannot fully qualify the bit after the sibling selector otherwise you are saying any nav siblings after the li, just change the bit after the tilda to match the li

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 196px;
  font-size: 64px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
}

nav ul {
  color: white;
  -webkit-padding-start: 32px;
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 18px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

nav ul li#title {
  min-width: 80%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li#menu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li#menu:hover {
  color: red !important;
}

nav ul li#menu:hover ~ li.item { /* target the class and use only li part after tilda */
  color: red !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

nav ul li#item.first {
  margin-top: 32px;
}

nav ul li.item {  /* target class instead of id */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  margin-left: -32px;
  height: 96px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

nav ul li.item:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}

a#menu {
  color: white !important;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a#menu:visited {
  color: white !important;
}

a:active {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="title">aytimothy's Website</li>
    <li id="menu"><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true">=</i></a></li>
    <li class="first item"><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="/forum">Forum</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="/support">Support</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Just a note, I `<a><li></li></a>` is so that I can used the `display: block;`-ed `<li>`(s) as a link, rather than just the text inside it being the link. Also, sidenote: That doesn't work.

Comment: @aytimothy it may be but it's invalid html - li is the only child element allowed in a ul.  Just switch it around and style it properly

Comment: I take that back. It _does_ work. Problem is that the snippet is too small.

Comment: The html structure is a rule, not a suggestion.  If you want to ignore it, then that's fine but then you will have browsers behaving in different ways as they try to fix your code for you.  You will also get penalised for seo and have other side effects.  So by all means go ahead and ignore it but then when you get other bugs because of it, don't forget that I told you you would.  I don't do this for the rep - I do this to try and help, if you don't want to learn that is fine too

Comment: It is not the asking for help that cost you rep, it's ignoring the help that's given.